# Best practice to upload file

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I'm looking for the RESTful best practice to upload a user photo and edit his information. The photo is placed on a local machine.

In my case I've implemented a method PUT resources/users/1 that allows to update all user data.

My request is very simple:

```
{
    "name": "John Doe",
    "photo": "photo URL"
}
```

Now my method only allows JSON data but I don't know how I must to upload the photo.

Can I do this in just one method?
Or Have I to implement another mehtod that upload a photo using MULTIPART_FORM_DATA and use?

Comment: if you're sending the photo url, in the server side you can retrieve the url. If the url can't be reached, then you have to send the image contents (maybe using POST and multipart)

Comment: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/

Comment: Yes use multipart.This is what it's there for